# Method for implementing objects in programming languages

Tags: c, struct, unions, language-implementation

**Overview**

I have been reading through several implementations of programming languages (mainly CPython and YARV, plus a couple smaller languages), and I have noticed two main different ways of implementing objects.

They both usually define some sort of enum representing the type of the object, for example

```
enum ObjectType {
    OBJECT_INT,
    OBJECT_FLOAT,
    OBJECT_STRING
    // loads more types
};
```

Then they usually go choose one of two different methods.

**Method 1**

Define structs for each different type of object, with a base object all these object can be cast to. For example:

```
// base object
struct Object {
    enum ObjectType type;
};

struct ObjectInt {
    struct Object object;

    // other fields specific to this type of object
};

struct ObjectFloat {
    struct Object object;

    // other fields specific to this type of object
};

struct ObjectString {
    struct Object object;

    // other fields specific to this type of object
};
```

**Method 2**

Create one struct for all objects, with a union inside.

```
struct Object {
    enum ObjectType type;

    union {
        struct {
            // fields specific to this type of object
        } as_int;
        struct {
            // fields specific to this type of object
        } as_float;
        struct {
            // fields specific to this type of object
        } as_string;
    };
};
```

**Summary**

Both methods allow you to represent the same things, but method 1 involves a lot more casting, whereas method 2 involves a lot more dereferencing. Does one offer anything the other doesn't, in terms of speed, space or features, or are they just two implementations of the same thing?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

An example of method 1 in YARV can be seen [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/include/ruby/ruby.h#L890)

Comment: Method 1 allows smaller allocations if structures have different sizes and second allows changing type of already existent objects.